# Selecting a word from a cell in datagridview, comparing it to the array of words c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I'm wiriting a programme which should do the following:

1) On button click import a *.doc file with a table in it into the datagridview

2) Get all the data (Family_Name &space& Name) (i.e. McFlurry John)

3) Cut the first word (i.e. "John" is left) **THE QUESTION**

4) Compare the word to the array (which is loaded from a txt file into a label and looks like a list of names in a column), line by line (i.e. John is compared to a list of names, such as James, Michael, Paul, etc.)

5) If the comparison returns true for any line - in a "Sex" columns it puts "MALE", so we know John is MALE (i.e. |1| McFlurry John | MALE |)

6) Do the same with the female names (the list is in the other label)

**THE QUESTION ITSELF: How to take the SECOND word from the DATAGRIDVIEW cell?**

What I've got so far :

```
**unnecessary word table load code**    
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //try
            //{

                string path = @"C:\PolM.txt";
                label6.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(label6.Text);
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if     (line.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()))

                    {

                        //show error msg

                       MessageBox.Show("GOT YA");
                    i++;


                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            //catch
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("NOT YEAH :(");
            //    break;
            //}
```

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Split(' ')[1]

Comment: Got that, thx, now it gives an Argument Exception at

'string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(label6.Text);'

"The path contains inappropriate symbols". Is it because of Cyrillic? I've got a txt file in C:\, UTF-8 :(

Comment: You can use [Path.GetInvalidPathChars()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check which characters are invalid, and test that again label6.Text's value.